# how to fix prop `name` does not match. server: "null" Client: "role"

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am creating a page for my client for registration. The page render properly as well however I keep getting this annoying warning in the console: Prop `name` did not match. Server: "null" Client: "role"

Here is how I have page:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import FormLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormLabel'
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import { RadioGroup } from '@material-ui/core';
import Radio from '@material-ui/core/Radio';
// import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
// import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import { FaUser } from 'react-icons/fa'
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
// import { Formik } from "formik";
import { parseCookies } from '@/helpers/index'
import Layout from '@/components/Layout'
import { API_URL } from '@/config/index'
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify'
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css'

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  paper: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(8),
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  avatar: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
  },
  form: {
    width: '100%', // Fix IE 11 issue.
    marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
  },
  submit: {
    margin: theme.spacing(3, 0, 2),
  },
}));

export default function RegisterPage({ token }) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const router = useRouter();
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    role: "",
    place: ""
  });
  //console.log(values);
  // const submitForm = async (values) => {
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    //console.log(values);
    e.preventDefault();


    const validate = () => {
      let errors = {};
      errors.msg = "";
      const regex = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]{2,}$/i;

      if (!values.firstName) {
        errors.msg += "First Name Is Required, "
      }

      if (!values.lastName) {
        errors.msg += "last Name Is Required, "
      }

      if (!values.email) {
        errors.msg += "Email is required, ";
      } else if (!regex.test(values.email)) {
        errors.msg += "Invalid Email, ";
      }

      if (!values.password) {
        errors.msg += "Password is required, ";
      } else if (values.password.length < 8) {
        errors.msg += "Password should be of minimum 8 characters length, ";
      }

      if (!values.role) {
        errors.msg += "Role is required, ";
      }

      if (!values.place) {
        errors.msg += "location is required, ";
      }

      return errors;
    }

    const validateResult = validate();
    if (validateResult.msg !== "") {
      toast.error(validateResult.msg)
    }
    else {
      console.log("after validation: ", values);
      let dataObject = {
        firstName: values.firstName,
        lastName: values.lastName,
        email: values.email,
        password: values.password,
        type: values.role,
        location: values.place

      }

      const res = await fetch(`${API_URL}/registration`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'x-access-token': `${token}`,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(dataObject),
      })

      const data = await res.json()

      if (data.status === 200) {
        toast.success(data.message)
        router.reload()
      }
      else {
        toast.error(data.message)
      }
    }
  };

  const handleChange = async (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    console.log(e.target);
    console.log(name, value);
    setValues({ ...values, [name]: value })
  }
  return (
    <Layout>
      {/* <React.Fragment> */}
      <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
        <CssBaseline />
        <div className={classes.paper}>
          <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
            <FaUser />
          </Avatar>
          <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
            New User Registration
          </Typography>
          <ToastContainer />
          <form className={classes.form} noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Grid container spacing={2}>
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                <TextField
                  autoComplete="fname"
                  name="firstName"
                  variant="outlined"
                  required
                  fullWidth
                  id="firstName"
                  label="First Name"
                  autoFocus
                  value={values.firstName}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                <TextField
                  variant="outlined"
                  required
                  fullWidth
                  id="lastName"
                  label="Last Name"
                  name="lastName"
                  autoComplete="lname"
                  value={values.lastName}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <TextField
                  variant="outlined"
                  required
                  fullWidth
                  id="email"
                  label="Email Address"
                  name="email"
                  autoComplete="email"
                  value={values.email}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <TextField
                  variant="outlined"
                  required
                  fullWidth
                  name="password"
                  label="Password"
                  type="password"
                  id="password"
                  autoComplete="current-password"
                  value={values.password}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={12}>
                <FormLabel component="legend">Role</FormLabel>
                <RadioGroup
                  aria-label="Role"
                  name="role"
                  row={true}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                >
                  <FormControlLabel value="ADMIN" control={<Radio />} label="ADMIN" />
                  <FormControlLabel value="PM" control={<Radio />} label="PM" />
                  <FormControlLabel value="TL" control={<Radio />} label="TL" />
                  <FormControlLabel value="AGENT" control={<Radio />} label="AGENT" />
                </RadioGroup>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={12}>
                <FormLabel component="legend">Location</FormLabel>
                <RadioGroup
                  aria-label="Location"
                  name="place"
                  //id="location"
                  row={true}
                  onChange={handleChange}>
                  <FormControlLabel
                    value="Hyderabad"
                    control={<Radio />}
                    label="Hyderabad" />
                  <FormControlLabel
                    value="Bangalore"
                    control={<Radio />}
                    label="Bangalore" />
                </RadioGroup>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Button
              type="submit"
              fullWidth
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              className={classes.submit}
            >
              Add New User
            </Button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </Container>
      {/* </React.Fragment> */}
    </Layout>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps({ req }) {
  const { token } = parseCookies(req)
  return {
    props: {
      token,
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a pretty common error with css in js libraries implemntation in next js. This happens because your server renders a `name=null` but your client is rendering it as `name='role'` so the check fails. There's a lot of discussion on this matter go through this. https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/11600#issuecomment-861035104

Comment: I think is an SSR issue, have you updated your `_document.tsx/jsx` file to handle ServerStyleSheets?

Comment: thank u for response @ReyYoung. and i had updated in _document.jsx Samuel goldenbaum. again i am getting the same.i had put log in handleChange method.here i am not able to get the value of name.this is the log                      
<input type="radio" class="PrivateSwitchBase-input-12" value="AGENT">

Comment: samuel goldmen can u please help me how to update this specific value in _document.jsx file